# debug Fast Api with docker compose in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pycharm, devops, fastapi

I am trying to debug mode from pycharm configurations but still no success. From terminal with **docker-compose up** it runs successfully in run mode and not in debug. Any ideas what is happening and what might be the issue?
Here's the docker file:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR api

CMD apt-get --assume-yes update \
    && apt-get --assume-yes upgrade \
    && apt-get --assume-yes install libpq-dev build-essential python3-dev

COPY api/ .

CMD ls

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT  chmod +x ./scripts/start.sh \
            && ./scripts/start.sh
```

start.sh script is as below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
set -e

# Unicorn is used for local development, gunicorn for production
# Pre-start script is used to execute commands that need to be run before
# opening the server such as migrations etc
U_EXEC_PATH=${U_EXEC_PATH:-./api/scripts/start-uvicorn.sh}
G_EXEC_PATH=${G_EXEC_PATH:-./api/scripts/start-gunicorn.sh}
PRE_START_PATH=${PRE_START_PATH:-./api/scripts/pre-start.sh}

# Common variables
MODULE_NAME=${MODULE_NAME:-api.app.main}
VARIABLE_NAME=${VARIABLE_NAME:-app}
export APP_MODULE=${APP_MODULE:-"$MODULE_NAME:$VARIABLE_NAME"}

export S_HOST=${S_HOST:-0.0.0.0}
export S_PORT=${S_PORT:-80}
export S_LOG_LEVEL=${S_LOG_LEVEL:-info}
export S_APP_ENV=${S_APP_ENV:-local}
echo "Checking for script in $PRE_START_PATH"
if [ -f $PRE_START_PATH ] ; then
    echo "Running script $PRE_START_PATH"
    . "$PRE_START_PATH"
else
    echo "There is no script $PRE_START_PATH"
fi

cd ..

if [ $S_APP_ENV = "local" ]
then
  echo "Local environment."
  echo "Starting start-uvicorn.sh"
  . "$U_EXEC_PATH"
else
  echo "$S_APP_ENV environment."
  echo "Starting start-gunicorn.sh"
  . "$G_EXEC_PATH"
fi
```

and start-uvicorn.sh

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
set -e

# Start Uvicorn with live reload
echo "host": $S_HOST
echo "port": $S_PORT
echo "module": $APP_MODULE
echo "log level": $S_LOG_LEVEL
exec uvicorn --reload --host $S_HOST --port $S_PORT --log-level $S_LOG_LEVEL "$APP_MODULE"
```

Comment: What do you mean by `debug mode`?

Comment: @Isabi I want to run with debug, not a regular run

Comment: Ok, but what does your 'start.sh` script do? Do you mind posting it? Also can you post the code that starts the `uvicorn` server? Still, I'm not sure if it's possible to debug via docker...usually debugging is easier to carry it out on bare metal machines

Comment: @Isabi I have edited the post, Take a look at it please
as far as I know it is possible to debug also with remote interpreter in pycharm

Comment: How do you run "run mode" and how "debug mode"? Where are you setting the environment variables?

Comment: to the .env file @Isabi
I run with docker compose up from terminal
while debug I try to do via pycharm

Comment: Ok, but variables like U_EXEC_PATH are declared somewhere, aren't they? Also, which command(s) do you use to build and run the docker container?

Comment: U_EXEC_PATH=${U_EXEC_PATH:-./api/scripts/start-uvicorn.sh}
G_EXEC_PATH=${G_EXEC_PATH:-./api/scripts/start-gunicorn.sh}
these are variables set here, to build I use docker-compose build and to run the docker container docker-compose up

Comment: How do you switch between run mode and debug mode?

Comment: by doing config in pycharm
similar to this 
https://testdriven.io/blog/django-debugging-pycharm/
but here I do a python config not django

Comment: Does it return an error or something?

Comment: no errors at all, it runs successfully in debug but cant show swagger